# ruby comparing two arrays of what they have in common

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to compare two arrays of what they have in common and not show any duplicates.

```
array1 = ['1. walking to the park to find some ice cream']
array2 = ['2. walking to the park to find ice cream and find more ice cream']
```

sample output:

```
walking to the park find ice cream
```

Comment: accept the [other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21688883/2767755) answer, my one is a worst one. I will delete this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do as :

```
a = '1. walking to the park to find some ice cream'
b = '2. walking to the park to find ice cream and find more ice cream'

match = Regexp.union(a.split(" "))
b.scan(match).uniq.join(" ")
# => "walking to the park find ice cream"
```

Comment: accept the [other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21688883/2767755) answer, my one is a worst one. I will delete this.

Answer (score 7):

1. Start with two strings
2. Split them both on spaces
3. Do an array intersection on them

---

```
a = '1. walking to the park to find some ice cream'
b = '2. walking to the park to find ice cream and find more ice cream'

a1 = a.split(" ")
b1 = b.split(" ")

common = a1 & b1
#=> ["walking", "to", "the", "park", "find", "ice", "cream"]
```

Regex will be slower. Here's a quick comparison between array union and using Regexp:

```
require 'benchmark'

def arr_only(a,b)
  a1 = a.split(" ")
  b1 = b.split(" ")
  a1 & b1
end

def w_regex(a,b)
  match = Regexp.union(a.split(" "))
  b.scan(match).uniq
end

n = 100_000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("arr:") { n.times {|i| arr_only(a, b) } }
  x.report("regex:"){ n.times {|i| w_regex(a, b) } }
end

#                   user     system      total        real
# arr:          1.030000   0.000000   1.030000 (  1.031033)
# regex:        4.970000   0.010000   4.980000 (  4.993263)
```